# Question about counting probabilities

Tags: probability

I have a question about the answer given by Andre Nicolas in the question below:

[A fair coin is tossed until either a head comes up or four tails are obtained.what is the expected no. of tosses?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/610136/a-fair-coin-is-tossed-until-either-a-head-comes-up-or-four-tails-are-obtained-wh)

If the sample space $S = \{H, TH, TTH, TTTH, TTTT\}$ we can't use the formula $P(E) = \frac{|E|}{|S|}$ where $|E|$ is the number of outcomes in the event $E$ because the outcomes of $S$ are not equally likely, correct? So, then how do we calculate the probabilities of elements in $S$? Do we count the probability of $H \in \{H, T\}$, probability of $TH \in \{TH, HT, HH, TT\}$, probability of $TTH \in \{TTH, TTT, HHH, THT, HHT, HTT, HTH, THH\}$ and probability of $TTTT$ in a set with $16$ outcomes?

Comment: Did you try anything?  What's the probability that the first toss is $H$?  What's the probability that the first two tosses are $TH$?  And so on.

Comment: @lulu, yes. The probability of $H$ is $\frac12$, the probability of $TH$ is $\frac14$, the probability of $TTH$ is $\frac18$. I am just counting the probabilities from the set up in my OP.

Comment: If it helps you, you can think of the set of all $16$ possible combinations of four tosses.  These, at least, are equiprobable.  Then by $H$ we just mean any sequence that begins with $H$ (so there are $8$ of them).

Comment: There you go.  So the probabilities are $\{\frac 12,\frac 14,\frac 1{16},\frac 1{16}\}$.  Like I say, if it helps with intuition just imagine that you throw four times, even if the game is over.  Thus there are $8$ ways to get $H$, $4$ ways to get $TH$, $2$ ways to get $TTH$, and exactly one way to get  $TTTH$ and $TTTT$.

Comment: @lulu, that's very logically satisfying. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> So, then how do we calculate the probabilities of elements in $S$?

In general you require *some model* of how the outcomes are generated that will enable you to evaluate their probabilities.   In this case the model is a *truncated geometric distribution* - you have a sequence of independent Bernoulli events (flips of a fair coin) and are counting trials until success *or* four failures; with success rate $1/2$.

So letting $X$ be the count of trials until success *or* four failures.   $\{X=2\}$ corresponds to $\{TH\}$ and so forth.  $$\mathsf P(X=k) = \begin{cases} 2^{-k} & : k\in\{1,2,3\} \\ 2^{-3} & : k=4\\0 & : k\notin\{1,2,3,4\}\end{cases}$$

> Do we count the probability of ... in a set with $16$  outcomes?

Yes, you can!   That is *also* a valid model.   Consider that if you (hypothetically) tossed the coin four times, you can group the sixteen *equally probable* outcomes into events by occurrence of the first head.   These events will correspond to those of your sample space, giving you a measure of their probability.

$$S'= \rm \Big\{\{\color{blue}{H}HHH, \color{blue}{H}HHT, \color{blue}{H}HTH, \color{blue}{H}HTT, \color{blue}{H}THH, \color{blue}{H}THT, \color{blue}{H}TTH, \color{blue}{H}TTT\}, \\ \{\color{blue}{TH}HH, \color{blue}{TH}HT, \color{blue}{TH}TH, \color{blue}{TH}TT\}, \\ \{\color{blue}{TTH}H, \color{blue}{TTH}T\},\\ \{\color{blue}{TTTH},\color{blue}{TTTT}\}\Big\}  $$

---

**tl;dr** $$S\times\mathsf P = \{{\rm (H, \tfrac 12), (TH, \tfrac 14), (TTH, \tfrac 18), (TTTH \cup TTTT, \tfrac 1{8})}\}$$

$$X\times\mathsf P = \{{\rm (1, \tfrac 12), (2, \tfrac 14), (3, \tfrac 18), (4, \tfrac 1{8})}\}$$

$\mathsf E(X) = \tfrac 12 +\tfrac 2 4+\tfrac 38+\tfrac 48 = \tfrac {15}{8}$

Answer (score 0):

If you have outcomes that are not equally likely, then you multiply the probability of that outcome by the outcome's quantity that you're measuring (in this case, number of tosses):

$$\frac{1}{2} \cdot 1 + \frac{1}{4} \cdot 2 + \frac{1}{8} \cdot 3 + \frac{1}{16} \cdot 4 + \frac{1}{16} \cdot 4 = 1 \frac{7}{8},$$

which rounds up to $2$.